# Rails Devise, extra params don't work in RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm having issues with adding usernames to the Devise controller.
The error message I get in the console when creating a new user is: "Unpermitted parameter: :username."

However I'm following the docs on github which says I should add parameters like this:

**In registrations_controller.rb** (this don't work)

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
    before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

    protected

    #If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_sign_up_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
    end
    
    #If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
    def configure_account_update_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])
    end
end
```

However doing this instead in the application control works:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        added_attrs = [:username]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
    end
end
```

I don't understand how one works and the other don't.

Comment: Have you configured you configured the routes to use your custom controller? For example with `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }`? I don't really see why you would overcomplicate this by creating two different callback methods like in the first example either.

Comment: The reason the later works is that DeviseController inherits from ApplicationController.

Comment: @max In routes i've added: 
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' } but I see I should have added registrations as well, I'll try that and give it a go!

The overcomplication is how the docs shows, and this file was autogenerated by devise and these were commented out. So i think it's weird it doest work when I've added it like the docs said.

Comment: @max it was the wrong route like you said! thank you, if you add is as a answer I will accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the routes to use your custom controller

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { 
  # ...
  registrations: "users/registrations" 
}
```

You don't need to two seperate callbacks either since `devise_parameter_sanitizer` keeps different parameters lists for different actions anyways.

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

    protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
        added_attrs = [:username]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
    end
  end
end
```